# How to add run parameters to a C++ project in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am using Nebeans 7.0 and its C++ plugin and I want to do something like this: `test.exe < in.txt > out.txt` when I run the project. Where can I add these parameters to the project in Netbeans? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Under `File`, `Project Properties`, `Run` the first entry is `Run Command`.  Click on the ellipsis to enter the additional information.

[image: Dialog Box]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it as y first guess and I put `"${OUTPUT_PATH} < in.txt > out.txt"` there. I was thinking the same that it should work but it returns an error that "the file does not exist or is not executable" when I run the project. It does exist and I am able to run it with these parameters from the terminal. Any ideas why it goes like that?

Comment: @Hollgam I'm not sure this will work, but try putting the full absolute path to the file.

Comment: did that as well, not working, also tried putting it to the root, not working either :(

Comment: @Hollgam I'm having a hard time getting it working how I'd like.  I think the `${OUTPUT_PATH}` part just gives you the name of the output directory.  In either case, I took that out and put the full filename and path to the exe then the < and then the full filename and path to the text file I was using for input.  It runs, but it appears that the system keeps waiting for input.  I'm not sure how to stave off that condition.  You might think about changing your code to send the input and output files in via `argv` rather than redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I've no C++ project plugin installed at the moment, but in Java and PHP you need to right click on the project name in project manager, select 'Properties' and find 'Run Configuration' (or something similar) in Categories tree