# netbeans: c project how to pass parameters for configure?

Tags: netbeans, configure

I want to do something close to
[How to add run parameters to a C++ project in Netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633710/how-to-add-run-parameters-to-a-c-project-in-netbeans)

but I don't want to pass command args to the running exe, I want to pass args to the configure script

When compiling the whole thing in command line I configure my project (Gimp) with the following options

```
configure --prefix=/opt/gimp-2.7 --without-libtiff --disable-python --without-dbus --disable-gtk-doc
```

Could I tweak netbeans to do the configure with proper options for me ?
Or is netbeans only able to do a make recursive at the root directory ? (So I need to run configure {my options} at least once before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans lets you pass arguments to configure script when you create a new C/C++ Project with Existing Sources. You can also edit the arguments and re-run the configure script if the project has already been created.

Steps to pass arguments to configure script when creating a new project:

1. File ->New Project
2. Select **C/C++ Project with Existing Sources**
3. Click **Next**
4. On the Select Mode Page, choose the folder containing the existing source and configure script.
5. Under **Select Configuration Mode:**, choose **Custom**.
6. Click Next
7. On the **Build Tool** page, choose **Using the makefile generated by the 'configure' script**
8. Enter your arguments for the configure script in the **Configure Arguments** box.
9. Click through the rest of the Wizard to create the project
10. NetBeans will run the configure script with the custom parameters and generate the Makefile when the wizard completes.

To edit the parameters passed to configure after the project has been created:

1. In the NetBeans Projects tree, expand your project, expand **Important Files**, right click on the **configure** script, and select **Properties**
2. Click the **...** button on the **Arguments** line and edit the arguments.
3. Click **Close**
4. Right click on the **configure** script and select **run**.
5. NetBeans will re-run the configure script with the new arguments and regenerate the Makefile.